# how to resize the uploading image and moving to a folder

Tags: php, image

i am trying to re size the uploading image and moving to a folder, i try with the blow code, but it is not work. i created a function for re sizing the photo, calling that function from another function, but image is not re sized, and photo is not moved to folder.

```
$final_save_dir = 'techpic';
$thumbname = $_FILES['tpic']['name'];
$imgName = $final_save_dir . '/' . $_FILES['tpic']['name'];
if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tpic']['tmp_name'], $final_save_dir . '/' . $_FILES['tpic']['name']))
{   
$this->createThumbnail($thumbname,"600","600",$final_save_dir,$final_save_dir);
}
function createThumbnail($image_name,$new_width,$new_height,$uploadDir,$moveToDir)
```

{
      $path = $uploadDir . '/' . $image_name;

```
  $mime = getimagesize($path);

  if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($path); }
  if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }
  if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }
  if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); }

  $old_x          =   imageSX($src_img);
  $old_y          =   imageSY($src_img);

  if($old_x > $old_y) 
  {
      $thumb_w    =   $new_width;
      $thumb_h    =   $old_y*($new_height/$old_x);
  }

  if($old_x < $old_y) 
  {
      $thumb_w    =   $old_x*($new_width/$old_y);
      $thumb_h    =   $new_height;
  }

  if($old_x == $old_y) 
  {
      $thumb_w    =   $new_width;
      $thumb_h    =   $new_height;
  }

  $dst_img        =   ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);

  imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y); 


  // New save location
  $new_thumb_loc = $moveToDir . $image_name;

  if($mime['mime']=='image/png'){ $result = imagepng($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,8); }
  if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,80); }
  if($mime['mime']=='image/jpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,80); }
  if($mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg'){ $result = imagejpeg($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,80); }

  imagedestroy($dst_img); 
  imagedestroy($src_img);

  return $result;
```

}

Comment: When trying to debug problems suppressing error reporting isn't the best idea (not that it's ever a good idea) : `@move_uploaded_file`

Answer (score 1):

```
function img($field = 'image', $width = null, $height = null, $crop = false, $alt = null, $turl = null) {
global $editormode;

$val = $field;

if (!$val)
    $val = 'no-image.png';


$alt = ($alt) ? $alt : stem(basename($val));

if ($width == null && $height == null)
    $imgf = get_dir() . $val;
else
    $imgf = gen_img($val, $width, $height, $crop);

if (!$imgf)
    return "";
$url = $imgf;

if (!$turl)
    return "<img src='$url' alt='$alt'/>\n";
else
    return "<a href='$turl'><img src='$url' alt='$alt'/></a>";
  }

function get_dir() {
return  "upload/";
}
function gen_img($fileval, $width, $height, $crop) {
if (!$fileval)
    return null;
$fname = get_dir() . $fileval;

if (!is_readable($fname))
    return null;

$stem = stem(basename($fname));

if ($width != null && $height != null) {
    $sz = getimagesize($fname);
    if ($sz[0] == $width && $sz[1] == $height) {
        return substr($fname, strlen(UPLOADROOT));
    }
    $sep = ($crop) ? '__' : '_';

    $outname = thumb_dir($fname) . $stem . $sep . $width . "x" . $height . "." . suffix($fname);

    if (!is_readable($outname) || filemtime($outname) < filemtime($fname))
        createthumb($fname, $outname, $width, $height, $crop);
}
else if ($width != null && $height == null) {
    $outname = thumb_dir($fname) . $stem . "_" . $width . "." . suffix($fname);
    if (!is_readable($outname) || filemtime($outname) < filemtime($fname))
        createthumb($fname, $outname, $width, $crop);
} else
    $outname = $fname;
//echo $outname; die();
return $outname;
}
function thumb_dir($path) {
$enddir = strrpos($path, "/");
$dir = substr($path, 0, $enddir) . "/.thumbnails/";
if (!file_exists($dir))
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
return $dir;
}
function createthumb($source, $dest, $new_w, $new_h = null, $crop = false) {
if (!file_exists($source))
    return null;

$src_img = 0;
$src_img = image_create($source);
$old_w = imageSX($src_img);
$old_h = imageSY($src_img);
$x = $y = 0;

if ($new_h == null) { // we want a square thumb, cropped if necessary
    if ($old_w > $old_h) {
        $x = ceil(($old_w - $old_h) / 2);
        $old_w = $old_h;
    } else if ($old_h > $old_w) {
        $y = ceil(($old_h - $old_w) / 2);
        $old_h = $old_w;
    }
    $thumb_w = $thumb_h = $new_w;
} else if ($crop) {
    $thumb_w = $new_w;
    $thumb_h = $new_h;
    $oar = $old_w / $old_h;
    $nar = $new_w / $new_h;
    if ($oar < $nar) {
        $y = ($old_h - $old_h * $oar / $nar) / 2;
        $old_h = ($old_h * $oar / $nar);
    } else {
        $x = ($old_w - $old_w * $nar / $oar) / 2;
        $old_w = ($old_w * $nar / $oar);
    }
} else if ($new_w * $old_h / $old_w <= $new_h) { // retain aspect ratio, limit by new_w
    $thumb_h = $new_w * $old_h / $old_w;
    $thumb_w = $new_w;
} else { // retain aspect ratio, limit by new_h
    $thumb_w = $new_h * $old_w / $old_h;
    $thumb_h = $new_h;
}

$dst_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w, $thumb_h);

imagecolortransparent($dst_img, imagecolorallocatealpha($dst_img, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($dst_img, false);
imagesavealpha($dst_img, true);

imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumb_w, $thumb_h, $old_w, $old_h);

image_save($dst_img, $dest);

imagedestroy($dst_img);
imagedestroy($src_img);
}
function image_create($source) {
$suf = strtolower(suffix($source));
if ($source == '.jpg')
    mylog("wtf", "source: $source", true);

if ($suf == "png")
    return imagecreatefrompng($source);
else if ($suf == "jpg" || $suf == "jpeg")
    return imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
else if ($suf == "gif")
    return imagecreatefromgif($source);
return null;
 }

 function image_save($dst_img, $dest) {
$suf = strtolower(suffix($dest));
if ($suf == "png")
    imagepng($dst_img, $dest);
else if ($suf == "jpg" || $suf == "jpeg")
    imagejpeg($dst_img, $dest);
else if ($suf == "gif")
    imagegif($dst_img, $dest);
 }
```

This your function which is put in your function file

that function has make Folder in the thumbnails in the image folder when you call the function file.

Following way to call the function when image display.

```
 <?php echo img('pages/sample_image.jpg', 122, 81, TRUE) ?>
```

Here the first is path of the image and 122:means width and 81:height and True/false True:crop the image and false: only resize the image.

And define the Uploadroot in your config file this path for the image folder.

Hope this works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For resizing an image in php you can use `Imagick::resizeImage` from [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php) or use [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php--net-10362)

Of course we can use Gd library which has low overhead by recommendation of @CD001. You can find explanation of GD re sizing in [this article](http://code.runnable.com/UnF-tFdudNt1AABt/how-to-resize-an-image-using-gd-library-for-php)

**Edit for More Explanation**

**for using `Imagick::resizeImage` you should see this description**

here is the prototype of the function:

```
bool Imagick::resizeImage ( int $columns , int $rows , int $filter , float $blur [, bool $bestfit = false ] )
```

*Parameters*

```
columns
Width of the image

rows
Height of the image

filter
Refer to the list of filter constants.

blur
The blur factor where > 1 is blurry, < 1 is sharp.

bestfit
Optional fit parameter.
```

**If you want to use gd library here is simple source code**

```
<?php
// File and new size
//the original image has 800x600
$filename = 'images/picture.jpg';
//the resize will be a percent of the original size
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;
// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output and free memory
//the resized image will be 400x300
imagejpeg($thumb);
imagedestroy($thumb);
```

Comment: GD library has a lower overhead on the server ... just saying.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. There is nothing related to correcting his/her code in here.

Comment: In two article out of three it has simple code. It is not necessary to copy contents @RST

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't mention it, I said you should use the comment function to mention it. Answer area is for answers. There is a reason why people (are asked to) post their code. Also keep in mind if this is the best answer it becomes a useless answer when the mentioned article is deleted  by its resp. owner.

Comment: Better answer now the explanation is added. However I still think the OP would like to know what is wrong with his code instead of alternative solutions. Ah well, maybe not :)